# When we enter a URL, what network events happen in what order?

Tags: networking

Before a TCP SSL handshake starts, a TCP 3-way handshake  is done. But according to the OSI model, an HTTPS connection is at layer 7, SSL encryption is done at layer 6, and the TCP connection is done at layer 4. Then how does the TCP connection come before the SSL handshake (I am talking about sender side)?

How does the OSI model flow when we hit a url?

Answer (score 2):

You can't address an IP packet to a host name; you can only address it to a numeric IP address. So the DNS lookup happens first.

Then you establish a TCP session to the IP address of the server, then establish a TLS session over that TCP session, then send an HTTP request over that TLS-encrypted TCP session.

Comment: "the send an HTTP request over that TLS-encrypted TCP session" is this done at Layer 7? I believe this is bottom up approach?

Comment: The overall HTTPS connection is driven by the application, but yes, the foundational layers of connectivity must be established before the higher layers can build on top of them. The HTTP request can't be sent without TLS being established, or it wouldn't be HTTPS. TLS has no way to get to the server without TCP. TCP has no way to get there without IP.